# $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $\gcd(|H|, |G/N|) = 1 \Rightarrow$ $H$ is a subgroup of $N$

Tags: group-theory

> $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $\gcd(|H|, |G/N|) = 1 \Rightarrow$ $H$ is a subgroup of $N$

I'll attempt to prove the contrapositive: 
$H$ isn't a subgroup of $N \Rightarrow \gcd(|H|, |G/N|) \neq 1$

We know that $|H|$ doesn't divide $|N|$ by Lagrange's Theorem. And we know that $|G/N| = \frac{|G|}{|N|} \Rightarrow |N| | |G|$

How do we show the $\gcd$ doesn't equal $1$ from this information? Do we assume the $\gcd$ is $1$? Or is there something more direct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the quotient map $p:G\rightarrow G/N$, $p(H)$ is a subgroup of $G/N$ its cardinal divides the cardinal of  $G/N$ (Lagrange) and the cardinal of $H$, since $|H|=|p(H)||Ker(p_{\mid H})|$ so it  divides $gcd(|H|,|G/N|)$ which is $1$. We deduce that $p(H)=1$ and $H\subset N$.